# In what order must a Stargate address be entered?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-movie

In the Stargate film, Daniel Jackson shows the known reason for having seven chevrons, i.e. that 6 points are required to locate a point in space plus the seventh being the point of origin:

[image: How Stargate addresses work]

We know that the last chevron is the point of origin in seven and eight chevron addresses. This leaves some questions open:

1. On an eight chevrons addresses, where is the "distance calculation chevron" in the address? Is it "6 chevrons, distance calc, point of origin" or "distance calc, 6 chevrons, point of origin"?
2. Is the order of the other six points relevant, i.e. it has to be something like "front, back, top, bottom, left right" or is it simply in pairs, e.g. "(top, bottom),(back,front),(left,right)" and the order in the brackets and the order of the brackets is irrelevant?
3. If the order of the 6 points is relevant, what is it?

From the explanation of Daniel Jackson, the "need to be pairs but order not relevant" would be most logical but I can't remember this being confirmed.

Comment: vtc - unclear what is being asked.

Comment: As far as movies/TV shows, I don't think this has ever been addressed. But the idea of the "pairs" of symbols does seem logical. I wonder if the books have touched on this.

Comment: @WOPR Could you please elaborate. If something is unclear, I'll happily clarify it.

Comment: @agarza The books, or maybe a fan asking somebody involved and getting an answer there.

Comment: @Shade I think you're getting hung up on your diagram; nothing says that the 3 lines have to be approximately perpendicular.  Imagine your cube with 3 dots on 1 face and 3 dots on the opposing face, with lines through the centre connecting pairs.  All that's important are the pairs, not the order.

Comment: Needing to specify the pairs is also not necessary. Given any six points, there's only one way to get lines between pairs of them to all intersect at a single point.

Comment: Honestly the math on that geometry is so sketchy I'd argue that their system and explanation is fairly post hoc. That is to say if you can do 6 points accurately why not just do the one you want.  Or use a tetrahedron to define the space instead of a cube?

Comment: Additionally while it's not the film canon - gates addresses in SG1 seem more like IP addresses or telephone numbers than vectors.  But that's out of scope and just my hunch.

Comment: @lucasbachmann because the DHDs compensate for stellar drift, so all the addresses are the coordinates of where the gates were when built.

Comment: The question is if there is a standard order like when you look at location in geometry it is always (x,y,z).  In theory it the order shouldn't matter since it is the point in the middle of the 6 points.

Comment: The Stargate address system has never really made sense. You can define a point as the intersection of three lines drawn between six points: sure. You identify points by constellations (so the symbols should be different on every gate): a bit rough, but we can assume the DHD compensates for inaccuracy. Constellations will be different form each gate: inconvenient. You need a point of origin: do you? Isn't it always just "here"? The point of origin is defined by a unique symbol for each gate: ...okay, so why isn't every gate address just the unique symbol used by the target gate for its "home"?